# Zend_Framework - No region found within the locale 'zh'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've had a look around the Internet and can't seem to find a solution to the problem I'm experiencing. I'm trying to use Zend_Currency to get the currency for China like so:

```
$currency = new Zend_Currency('CN');
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Currency_Exception' with message 'No region found within the locale 'zh'' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php on line 561
```

This is on a fresh install of Zend Framework 1.12.3, and as far as I'm aware I'm not doing anything incorrect here. From the error I can see that Zend has matched the country code to the locale.

This is a problem as my application relies on obtaining currency information from a country code. I have no issues with GB, US etc.

I've had a look in `Zend/Locale/Data` and can confirm the `zh.xml`, `zh_CN.xml` locale files are there, but I'll admit I'm not 100% what I'm looking for in each!

Anyone have any ideas about what the issue is and how I might go about fixing it?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is an edit to reflect comment discussion.

It seems that Zend_Locale returns `zh` when given the country code `CN`, rather than the expected string `zh_CN`. This means that I am unable to find anything consistent that I can pass to Zend_Currency to avoid errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Zend mismanaging the CN region.
In fact, if I'm not mistaken, the name of the locale is `zh_Hans_CN` and when it manages the `CN` region Zend see if it is part of the variable `$_localeData` (in Zend/Locale.php file) and as this is not the case, it decomposes `zh_Hans_CN` and keeps only `zh` he does not know either.

If you want to keep the same principle as `$currency = new Zend_Currency('CN');` 
you can try it:

```
Zend_Locale::getLocaleToTerritory('CN');
```

will retrieve the correct locale by default. (like `'US'` give `'en_US'`)
Which gives:

```
$currency = new Zend_Currency(Zend_Locale::getLocaleToTerritory('CN'));
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. This is interesting indeed. Also thanks for the heads up on Zend_Locale::getLocaleToTerritory, this will definitely sort out my problem for the time being!

Comment: You're welcome:It was also very interresting to spend time to understand and find a solution, so thank you for that question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way;)

```
$currency = new Zend_Currency('zh_CN');
```

Comment: @James - tell me if this works correctly in Your further code. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Passing the locale string like you suggested does work! The only issue is Zend_Locale seems to be inconsistent with what it returns. For example if I do Zend_Locale('CN'); it returns 'zh', whereas I'd expect 'zh_CN'. This of course results in the original issue, so is it that there is a bug in Zend_Locale that can't deal with CN? I feel I can't rely on a consistent input to use with Zend_Currency.